# Discord.py API: how do I properly refer to discord user if I have their username?

Tags: python, api, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to call this function:

```
async def send_dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)
```

with this code:

````
for i in pokeractiveplayers:
        #name = ???
        card1 = pokerdeck[0]
        pokerdeck.pop(0)
        card2 = pokerdeck[0]
        pokerdeck.pop(0)
        await send_dm(ctx, name, f"""Your hand is: ```
        {card1}, {card2}
        ```""")
````

however I don't know how to properly refer to a user so that the function accepts it. The information I have is the username and #### of the user (e.g blahblah#1234) but I only have it as a string and when I tried inputting it as the "member" arg it was not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the member object first using and pass it to the `send_dm` function. You can do this using `get_member()`.

````
    user = client.get_member(user_id)
    await send_dm(ctx, user, f"""Your hand is: ```
    {card1}, {card2}
    ```""")
````

Comment: I tried get_member() but I recieved an error as it's apparently outdated, as seen here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2138 - so i used the alternative offered, client.fetch_user but when i enter the id like so: client.fetch_user(152820855544610816) I get this error: TypeError: fetch_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'